# Error creating path in laravel when running scheduling

Tags: laravel, scheduling

When i create sitemap using cron and scheduling in laravel: i have add path by route('web.index') but when show in sitemap.xml the path becomes http://localhost/example.com/ in when the correct path must be https://example.com.

Can anyone help me how to fix it properly. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: What is the value of `APP_URL` in your `.env` file? That value is used when constructing/reference routes when running Laravel from your Command line, i.e. when running a `CRON` Scheduler task, and you probably just need to update it to `https://example.com`

Comment: @TimLewis APP_URL in .env: example.com . Thank you, I changed to https://example.com in .env file and in config/app and success

Comment: Excellent! So yeah, by default, Laravel will use the URL of the host (running locally is `localhost`, etc.), but when run via CLI (something like `php artisan tinker`, or `php artisan schedule:run` for `CRON`), it needs an external variable to determine the host URL, which is what `APP_URL` in your `.env` file does. Glad you got it working, cheers!